# Не могу получить properties файл лежащий внутри jar

Tags: java, сервер, плагин, minecraft

Я учился писать плагины для minecraft, столкнулся с проблемой я создал файл messages.properties, у меня нет доступа к нему. Когда я использую `FileInputStream fis = FileInputStream("messages.properties");` он ищет файлы в корневой папке сервера. Сам файл лежит внутри jar. Если открыть jar как архив [image: Содержимое TestPlugin.jar]

Код:

```
try {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("messages.properties");
    properties.load(fis);
    BaneLogger.log(Level.INFO, properties.getProperty("NoAccessCommand"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Ошибка (Возможно будет полезно):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: messages.properties (Не удается найти указанный файл)
        at ru.banejil.testplugin.Main.logProp(Main.java:36) ~[?:?]
        at ru.banejil.testplugin.Main.onEnable(Main.java:22) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-794]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:370) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-794]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:500) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-794]
        at com.rylinaux.plugman.util.PluginUtil.load(PluginUtil.java:366) ~[?:?]
        at com.rylinaux.plugman.command.LoadCommand.execute(LoadCommand.java:114) ~[?:?]
        at com.rylinaux.plugman.PlugManCommandHandler.onCommand(PlugManCommandHandler.java:95) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:45) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-794]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:159) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-794]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:826) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-794]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:788) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-794]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.handleCommandQueue(DedicatedServer.java:470) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-794]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:437) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-794]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:1347) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-794]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1135) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-794]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:291) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-794]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) [?:?]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: messages.properties (Не удается найти указанный файл)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:211) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:153) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:108) ~[?:?]
        at ru.banejil.testplugin.Main.logProp(Main.java:32) ~[?:?]
        ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, потому что `FileInputStream` ищет файл, чтобы его открыть. Файл внутри джара -- это ресурс, его можно прочесть с помощью `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`

Comment: Кто тоже не понимал почему это решение не работает надо ```new InputStreamReader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name))``` никто на всех форумах не сказал что нужно добавить ```new InputStreamReader()```